# syntax error on mysql query width Select and Limit

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I get a error that  a query on a mysql database has a wrong syntax.
The code should check if a string {Rfid} is present in a Tags database and if not create it. The exception is caused in the first MySqlcmd.CommandText
But i dont see it, they're normal mysql verbs, the only speciality perhaps might be that Rfid can contain spaces, but i fail to see why that would give a problem.

```
OpenConnection(); //a function to connect, no problems here.
MySqlDataReader reader;
MySqlcmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM 'Tags' WHERE 'UHFRFID'=\"'{Rfid}'\"   LIMIT 1;";
reader = MySqlcmd.ExecuteReader();  // >> crashes

        //create a new tag in table, if its unknown.
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlcmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO `Tags` (`TagId`,  `UHFRFID`, `Gate1`) VALUES(NULL,\"'{Rfid}'\",  NULL);";
                MySqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                MySqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            { }
```

The MySQL error i get is:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near ''Tags' WHERE 'UHFRFID'='tag 13 00000' LIMIT 1' at line 1'

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate then please edit it to explain _why_. You may also ping the person who closed it by putting an @ in front of their username. I'm sure they'd be more than happy to reopen if they made a mistake - but you need to explain why it is not a duplicate not just assert it!

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
MySqlcmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM 'Tags' WHERE 'UHFRFID'=\"'{Rfid}'\"    LIMIT 1;";
```

with

```
MySqlcmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM `Tags` WHERE `UHFRFID`=\"'{Rfid}'\"    LIMIT 1;";
```

`Tags`  and `UHFRFID` are table/column names and not string values.

You have to use back ticks `` ` `` instead of single quotes `'`

Comment: Well no Tags was a table, but the  single quotes made the query look like if it where a column. just noted it after posting it here, but your on the same track so i reward it.

Comment: @user3800527 right, i've updated my answer thank you